# Redirecionar VPN ou DNS para Proxy

Tags: windows, redirecionamento, dns, proxy, vpn

Eu tenho um servidor proxy na minha máquina na porta **8080**, através do proxy eu consigo controlar o tráfego de pedido e resposta feito pela máquina cliente.

Porém, eu gostaria de utilizar esse proxy juntamente com meu servidor de VPN.

Meu servidor de VPN foi criado utilizando Softether VPN Server.

Tudo está instalado em uma máquina com Windows Server 2012. Eu já tentei utilizar DNS, tentei fazer várias modificações diferentes no SecureNAT/DHCP do Softether para reconhecer o DNS e através do DNS redirecionar para o Proxy, porém eu não consegui de maneira alguma.

Eu gostaria de saber se alguém teria uma solução.

O meu plano era que a maquina cliente se conectasse ao VPN, e todo acesso a websites seria redirecionado ao proxy.

Comment: Marlon, não entendi direito. Os dois serviços estão na mesma máquina? Já tentou colocar como gateway da vpn o ip do proxy?

Comment: Então Andre, o VPN e o Proxy estão na mesma máquina, e a maquina cliente em rede diferente que atualmente está acessando o proxy, porém gostaria de fazer a maquina cliente acessar o VPN e através do VPN os websites acessados serem tratados pelo proxy (que está na maquina da vpn).